# javascript loopback check if at least one property is unique

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

in my project that is using loopback, before creating a new instance of a specific model, i want to verify that at least one of two properties is unique. (if they are not- then i don't need to create it, since i already have the same exact instance for all im concerned).

I have looked all around the web for answers, and from what i gathered, the code should look something like this:

```
Installation.validatesuniquenessof('driverId', ['deviceToken']);
```

where the second parameter is actually an array (in this case with one value), of the scope in which i will be looking for uniqueness. is this correct? i seem to be having problems with this.

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried.

Comment: And please explain more thoroughly. Unique how, in what realm?

Comment: i have a model called installation, which has many properties, two of them are installableId and deviceToken. when i create a new installation to put in to the database (mongodb) i want to know if either one of them is unique. if none of those properties are unique, there is no need for me to create a new installation. this the code i tried: Installation.validatesUniquenessOf('installableId', 'deviceToken'); it seems to validate uniqueness of first parameter and if not unique- throw error, even though i would be just as happy if the second parameter was unique.